# How do you say A leads to B leads to C in one single sentence?

Tags: grammar

Saying that A leads to B leads to C in one single sentence.

I want to say フィードバックを回収すること**により**、消費者の気持ちを理解する**ことで**、企業はもっといい商品を出すようになる, but i dont know if this is grammatically correct?

Please also do share if you have any better alternatives, Thanks!

Comment: Take this into the account too: …回収して…理解することで.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your sentence looks perfect to me. Using ～により or ～ことで twice in a single sentence would have made your sentence look clumsy. You did a good job by choosing a different expression.

Note that 回収 usually means collecting something physical. If this sentence also covers online surveys, フィードバックを取得する might be better.